# RecyclerView not showing or content shifted below toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat

I want a view with a toolbar, a floating action button over the toolbar, some content and a recyclerview below all of that.

Layout #1 has the fab and the content correctly positioned, but the recylerview doesn't show.

The other layout shows the recyclerview, but most of the content is hidden underneath the toolbar.

I have tried various combinations of these 2 examples, but cannot get my desired outcome.

What am I doing wrong here?

Layout #1:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/time_holder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd_alarm_time"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_clock_black" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/time_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvalarmtime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tv_alarm_time"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvalarmtimeset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvalarmtime"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/day_holder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_alarm_calendar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd_alarm_repeat"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_black" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/day_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvalarmrepeat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tv_alarm_repeat"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvalarmdays"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvalarmrepeat"
                android:text="@string/tv_alarm_no_repeat"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_holder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_alarm_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd_alarm_title"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_black" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvalarmtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tv_alarm_title"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvalarmname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvalarmtitle"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/medicationHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/material_lightgreen_100"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_alarm_supplements"
            android:textColor="@color/material_lightgreen_500"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerMedications"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    style="@style/fab_layout_margin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_ic_add"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="end|bottom|right"
    app:rippleColor="@color/primary_light" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: layout #1 image]

Layout #2

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/time_holder"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_alarm_time"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_clock_black" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/time_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvalarmtime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/tv_alarm_time"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvalarmtimeset"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/tvalarmtime"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/day_holder"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_alarm_calendar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_alarm_repeat"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_black" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/day_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvalarmrepeat"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/tv_alarm_repeat"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvalarmdays"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/tvalarmrepeat"
                        android:text="@string/tv_alarm_no_repeat"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/title_holder"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_alarm_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_alarm_title"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_black" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/title_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvalarmtitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/tv_alarm_title"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvalarmname"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/tvalarmtitle"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/medicationHeader"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@color/material_lightgreen_100"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/txt_alarm_supplements"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_lightgreen_500"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerMedications"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        style="@style/fab_layout_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_ic_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="end|bottom|right"
        app:rippleColor="@color/primary_light" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: layout #2 image]

I've searched all over the place and tried many different combinations; the 2 versions shown here are the best of what I've found.

Can anybody help me?